# python. hog в scikit

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Ставлю размер pixels_per_cell 9х9 для 9 градаций. Размер изображения 126х126. Картинки получаются норм. Но если я получаю вектор фичей, то получается бред: 17424 фичи. Откуда такое большое число!? Если посчитать число зон на картинке, то их 14х14, как и должно быть. Более того, если я меняю размер блока (cells_per_block), то число фичей уменьшается. Хотя, по логике, должно оставаться неизменным. 17424 фичи получается для блока размером 2x2

[hog](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/529070) в scikit-learn.

[image: HOG]

---

Пример изображения:

[image: Пример изображения]

Пример HOG:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`{'cell_size': [14, 14], 'block_size': [2, 2], 'n_levels': 9, 'block_norm': u'L2'}`

`len(hog) == 900`

Comment: @stackflow да, так и есть

Comment: Можно увидеть пример кода с примером изображения?

Comment: По какой логике при уменьшении размера блока число фич должно уменьшаться? Дополните вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import hog

im = np.random.normal(0, 1.0, (126, 126))

hf = hog(im, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(9,9), cells_per_block=(2,2))
print(hf.shape)
```

У меня указанный код выдает `(6084,)`, что правильно.

Общий feature vector - это набор вектор фич каждого блока. Для каждого блока (block) фичи - это набор гистограмм для **всех** ячеек (cell) данного блока (block).

- Количество элементов (orientations) в гистограмме каждой ячейки: 9.
- Количество ячеек в блоке (при `cells_per_block=(2,2)`): 2*2=4.
- То есть, количество фич одного блока: `9*2*2=36`.

Теперь про количество блоков. Главное: блоки **пересекаются**. То есть, блоки получаются путем сдвига на одну *ячейку*, а не на размер блока. Таким образом количество блоков, например, по горизонтали: `всего_ячеек - размер_блока_в_ячейках + 1`. Общее количество блоков: `(126/9) - 2 + 1 = 13`.

В итоге общее количество фич `количество_блоков * количество_фич_на_блок`: `13 * 13 *36 = 6084`

Природу возникновения количества фич `17424 = 2*2*2*2*3*3*11*11` для изображения данного размера `(126, 126)` я не очень понимаю. Изображение размера `(207, 207)` при прочих неизменных параметрах дает именно такое количество фич.

На всякий случай:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

python -c "import skimage; print(skimage.__version__)"
0.13.0
```